# Errors booting CentOS 5 after RAID disk issue

Tags: linux, centos, raid, centos5, hardware-raid

I've got a linux appliance running on an `IBM X3850 X5 type 7143` box.  CentOS 5.

It has a RAID 5 configuration with 6 drives.  2 of the drives went down. One was bad and needed to be replaced.  The other was just offline and came back online.

The array came back online after the offline drive was back up and at that point we replaced the other drive so it could rebuild.  At this point, all drives are showing as being online and the RAID array is showing a healthy status in the MegaRAID BIOS.

All that being said, I'm still getting errors when I try to boot CentOS.  Specifically, I'm seeing:

```
Loading dm-message.ko module
Loading dm-raid45.ko module
device-mapper: dm-raid45: initialized v0.25941    
Waiting for driver initialization.
Scanning and configuring dmraid supported devices
Creating root device.
Mounting root filesystem.
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds. 
EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mod. 
Setting up other filesystems.
Setting up new root fs
setuproot: moving /dev failed: No such file or directory
no fstab.sys, mounting internal defaults
setuproot: error mounting /proc: No such file or directory 
setuproot: error mounting /sys: No such file or directory
Switching to new root and running init. 
unmounting old /dev
unmounting old /proc
unmounting old /sys
ERROR opening /dev/console: No such file or directory
Trying to use fd 0 instead
WARNING: can't access (null)
exec of init ((null)) failed!!!: Bad address
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempting to kill init!
```

Any thoughts on what could be going on here and how to troubleshoot it?  I'm not sure why CentOS would have issues if the RAID array was successfully rebuilt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial ramdisk is failing to root pivot, because you have filesystem errors on your root device.

Your array has consistency problems due to it becoming damaged rather than just degraded at one point. Now that you've propagated those filesystem inconsistencies throughout the array by re-syncing it (nothing you could have done about that, really), you'll need to fix them at the filesystem level.

Do an offline fsck to your root filesystem, and any other filesystems that reside on this array. You might have to rely on a backup to restore your machine. This is one of the many reasons that RAID 10 wins out on RAID 5 or 6, and why 5 and 6 are seeing far less adoption than they used to. That being said, RAID is never a backup, and a damaged array will have a damaged filesystem on it, no matter the RAID level.

Answer (score 1):

So the swap partition and references to it in /etc/fstab need to be checked and fixed if neccessary. At least that’s obvious from this example.
So not only do you need to fix the swap space, check /etc/fstab and fix any references if required but you also need to recreate the initrd.

There is example on this link
[Centos5 Fix](https://blog.laimbock.com/2014/09/25/howto-fix-centos-5-vm-not-booting-with-a-kernel-panic/)